# MaskedTextBox mask in Extended Wpf Toolkit

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, maskedtextbox

I am trying to create mask for MaskedTextBox, which allows to input alphanumeric string 3-5 characters long. I was trying for example `<xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="&amp;&amp;&amp;AA" ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}"/>` without success, value is available only when reaching full 5 characters.

Comment: I took a look at [MaskedTextBox mask rules](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MaskedTextBox~Mask.html) and it seems they have copy-paste mistake in docs for `A` and `a`. you probably need `Mask="&amp;&amp;&amp;aa"`?

Comment: It works, thanks. But now I have another requirement - there cant be any spaces in that string and I am afraid that it cant be done with mask, only with checking using regular expression.